# correct and best way to handle 'database is locked' errors with twisted.enterprise.adbapi

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, twisted

I am using twisted.enterprise.adbapi with sqlite3 database adapter and "runInteraction()".

I keep on getting "sqlite3.OperationalError : database is locked" errors. 
I understand the problem, multiple threads try to access the DB and it being already locked by a thread it raises this exception. My question is what is the standard/correct Twisted way of dealing with this?

I already found an answer here:
http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2009-June/019848.html

But doesn't limiting the connection pool to one connection slow down the whole application on long queries?
Still it doesn't solve accessing the database from two applications.

Is there a better way you can think of?

King regards, Florian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But doesn't limiting the connection pool to one connection slow down the whole application on long queries?

SQLite doesn't allow concurrent connections;  Not from the same process and not from different processes;  It maintains a lock flag in the database to specifically prevent other processes from using that database file while one process is still using it.  if you have a slow query, it will block other connections, it doesn't matter if they are in process or otherwise.

If that is a problem, the solution is simple, don't use sqlite.

Comment: So yes, I think you are perfectly right. Wonder why I havn't found that information anywhere, but the solution is easy: I'll switch to another rdbms. Thanks.